# Change global variables from inside class method

Tags: python, class, methods, global

When I try to execute the code below, the first_list gets modified while no changes occur to the second one. Is there a way to replace an outside list with a brand new list, or calling list methods is the only thing I'm allowed to do from inside class methods? I tried adding global keyword before the assignment operation, but it produces a syntax error.

```
first_list = []
second_list = []


class MyClass:

    def change_values(self):
        first_list.append('cat')
        second_list = ['cat']

 test = MyClass()
 test.change_values()
 print(first_list)
 print(second_list)
```

Comment: The problem is that when you use the assignment operator as you did for second_list, the interpreter assumes you're trying to add an attribute to the local function's namespace - a consequence of the local function's namespace coming before the global namespace in the interpreter's lookup order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: It's almost **NEVER** a good idea to have global variables with mutable state. You should use module level variables just as constants or singletons. If you want to change a value of a variable you should pass it as a parameter to a function and then return a new value from a function.

Said that the answer to your question would be either:

```
first_list = []
second_list = []


class MyClass:
    def change_values(self):
        first_list.append('cat')
        second_list[:] = ['cat']

test = MyClass()
test.change_values()
print(first_list)
print(second_list)
```

or:

```
first_list = []
second_list = []


class MyClass:
    def change_values(self):
        first_list.append('cat')
        global second_list
        second_list = ['cat']

test = MyClass()
test.change_values()
print(first_list)
print(second_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the global keyword inside the function